# Get selected value dynamically and include that in if condition

Tags: php, jquery

How to get value from select box dynamically without loading page and use that value in if condition ?

Comment: The select box doesn't exist till the page is loaded.

Comment: server side if or client side if ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"without loading page"*

I'm going to guess that you mean "without submitting the form" and reloading the page, since you obviously can't get the value of a control on a page without loading that page.

Just do something like this:

```
var val = $("#idOfSelectHere").val();
if (val === "something" || val === "something else") {
    // do something
} else if (val === "whatever" && someOtherCondition) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Obviously you can add as many conditions and `else if`s as you like...

Further reading: [jQuery's `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided code but a previous question should provide good answers.

[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)

When you say without loading page, I assume you mean without hitting submit and reloading the page.

You can also use jquery to get your result... assuming the pulldown is num states.

```
 $("#numstates").val() //the value of the selected option
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the default selected option of selectbox use,

```
var selected = $("#selectboxId").find(":selected").text();
```

You can use following way to get the user selected value,

```
$("#selectboxId").change(function () {
       alert($(this).val()); 
});
```